# A simple inequality involving expectations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a simple question but want to make sure my argument is fully sound.

I'm given a random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and a random variable $Y$ *dependent* on $X$. I know that $0 \leq Y \leq 1$. Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[YX]=0$ ?

My thoughts: From what is given we have the following inequality

\begin{equation}
-X \leq XY \leq X
\end{equation}

And taking expectations on both sides of the inequality we get

\begin{equation}
0 \leq \mathbb{E}[XY] \leq 0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[XY]=0
\end{equation}

**Question**: Is this correct? Thank you for your help.

**Motivation**: If we let $-1 \leq Y \leq 1$ we could take $Y = \text{sign}X$ and then $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[|X|]$ which is not zero. Hence I think the statement is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot multiply inequalities by negative numbers so your argument is not valid.  ($Y \leq 1$ does not imply $XY \leq X$). In fact $EXY$ need not be $0$. Take for example $Y=\frac  1  2(1+\frac X {1+|X|})$. Then $0 \leq Y \leq 1$ and $EXY >0$.